# how do I extract the elements with the same value in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a group of data in the format of:

```
log = [[timestamp, x_coordinate, y_coordinate]]
```

which looks something like:

```
log = [[500, 20, 20], [500, 25, 25], [500, 22, 25], [1000, 20, 25], [1000, 30, 25]...]
```

There is quite a lot of data so I want to process them faster. Is there a way to process the data with the same timestamp altogether and then move on to the next timestamp?

So far I have tried to use for loop to do the favor, but it still works very slow. Is there another way to process the data faster?

```
for item in log:
     if item[0] == ts:
          draw_tracking(output_img, item[1], item[2])
```

Desired output is a bit complicated. I want to draw a box based on the data from the list. I have this function:

```
def draw_tracking(img, x, y):
    pt_1 = (x, y)
    pt_2 = ((x+5), (y+5))
    cv2.rectangle(img, pt1=pt_1, pt2=pt_2, color=(255,0,0), thickness=5)
    plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: can you show the desired output

Answer (score 2):

You can do a pre process first, something like this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

grouped = defaultdict(list)

for item in log:
    grouped[item[0]] = (item[1], item[2])
```

Now, when you want to draw a timestamp (`ts`), you can do:

```py
for item in grouped[ts]:
    draw_tracking(output_img, item[0], item[1])
```

This way you only iterate over the full list onece, for the preprocess, then, for each timestamp, you only iterate over that timestamp "entries".

Comment: Maybe you mean ```for item in log: grouped[item[0]] = (item[1], item[2])```.

Comment: @xpie, yes, you are right, thak you, i have changed it

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna to find out the data of a given timestamp, the fllowing code may works:

```
[{'timestamp': _[0], 'data': _} for _ in log if _[0] == YOUR_TIMESTAMP ]
```

if you wanna to group the data by timestamp, you may consider the code bellow

```
{_[0]: [__ for __ in log if __[0]==_[0]]  for _ in log}
```